# How to use Linear Discriminant Analysis to identify an image in the training folder with a similar image in the testing folder?

Tags: c#, image, lda

I have a windows forms project and I have a dataset called the `ATTDataSet`, the folder has two folders, the `training` and `testing` folders, each contain similar images in the same order. I have a form with two picture box with the labels `original image` and `recognized image`. I need help with processing an image from the training folder to train this program to save the name of that image and identify a similar image in the testing folder with this algorithm `Linear Discriminant Analysis`. I want to train the program first to learn a face and then later I will implement a button handler to identify all the images in the second folder with the same pattern as that which was recognized in the learn process. The code am using is below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace LDA_FaceR
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //read the first image in the ATT data set folder
          
            string path = "C://Users//TimothyFarCry5//Documents//visual studio 2015//Projects//LDA-FaceR//LDA-FaceR//ATTDataSet//Training//S1_1.jpg";
            Bitmap mymap = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(path));
            pictureBox1.Image = mymap;
            //program so that the program intitiates an LDA sequence to learn the image
            

        }
     //this method tries to identify images from the second testing folder with the LDA
     //pattern stored in the learn process, please help
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

After digging online a little, I learned that I need to use classes to do this and I need to express the images in the database as a one dimesnion vector and then I should compute the mean and then subtract the mean from all images and then get eigenfaces. How do I express an image in the format shown below? The images have been expressed in vector form, how to do this is the problem and then later I can try to compute the mean.
[image]
This project is really important, Kudos to all who are willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need at least some linear algebra library which can compute vector-matrix multiplication and an inverse of a matrix. In such case you compute covariance of all your data, take it's inverse, and the discriminative vector is then a vector between means (centers) of two classes multiplied by the inverse.

There are libraries which implement LDA. For example Egmu CV (which is sort of OpenCV in C#) has FisherFaceRecognizer which should implement Fischer Discriminant Analysis which is almost exactly LDA (the differences are not important). https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.1/document/html/80c70818-c4e1-e5a7-6c74-1ce3d6bd1be4.htm

Anyway, LDA for face recognition is not a good idea and it will not work much (almost at all). Reasonable approach is to take a CNN specifically trained to extract facial embeddings and compare those embedding using simple distance function (e.g. L2) to get a facial identity distance of images. Many "deep learning" frameworks can be used from C# and you can download pretrained face recognition networks.

Comment: @Michael Hradis, God bless you man, lemme install the libraries